# MySQL Query Compare a value to get another

Tags: mysql, database

I have one database that contains two tables named 'players' and 'morestats'
In the table 'players' I have the columns 'id' and 'player_name'
In the table 'morestats' I have the columns 'id' and 'stat1', 'stat2', etc..

I have to get the value 'stat1' from the table 'morestats' and then search for the player_name of the table 'players' that is egual to the id of both the tables.

All I have to do is this:
**Search for the row that has the same ID from 'morestats' and 'players', then get player name.**

Comment: Show us the table structure along with the expected result. Also the query you have tried.

Comment: @RagingBull
players: ("id","playername")
morestats: ("id","stat1","stat2")

Comment: And the query you have tried?

Comment: I don't know what to do..

Comment: Sounds like a basic JOIN.

Comment: @user3742637: Stat1 and stat2 are ids of players, right?

Comment: No, stat1 and stat2 are some statistics numbers..

Comment: @user3742637: That is what I said, please show some sample data and the relation between those tables.

Comment: @RagingBull:
Of course, so:
players: ("1", "UserName")
morestats: ("1", "10", "17")
The ids between players and morestats are the same. I have to get a value from Morestats checking that the username of the table players  has egual id with the table morestats.

Comment: @user3742637: That can be done using a simple JOIN. Learn more about different joins. A good start [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) or [**here**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm).

Comment: I have tried this:

    SELECT morestat.stat1, morestat.id, players.id, players.player_name FROM morestat INNER JOIN players WHERE morestat.id=players.id AND players.player_name='".$_GET["username"]."'

But I have failed something..

Comment: @RagingBull can you check this string?

Comment: @user3742637: Selflearning is the best learning. You need to use `ON` as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stat1, player_name
FROM morestats
INNER JOIN players
USING(id);
```

This will display a table with each row containing the value of stat1 and the corresponding player_name.
If you want to filter this table you have to put an `WHERE` statement before the end of the query. Example: `WHERE stat1 = 'valuetosearch';`

Comment: But before I have to check that the IDs between the two tables are egual or not..

Comment: you don't have to do this because `INNER JOIN` will join the two tables, while `USING(id)` specifies that the value of the column `id` must match in both tables.